# My router doesn't work as expected

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

this is the router code

```
Router.route('screens',  {
  path: '/screenshots/:_id',
  template: 'screens',
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    Session.set( "currentRoute", "screens" );
    Session.set("screenshots", this.params._id);
    this.next();
  }
});
```

this is the helper for screenshots template

```
Template.screens.helpers({
    ss: function () {
        var screenshots = Session.get("screenshots");
        return Products.findOne({ _id: screenshots});
    }
});
```

and am calling it here

```
<h4><a href="/screenshots/{{_id}}">Click to view the Screenshots</a>
```

When i click to view the screenshots URL, the URL should be this `/screenshots/:_id` based on my router configuration, but what i see in the browser is `/screenshots/` without the `_id` and the page shows 404 - NOT FOUND.

Is it possible to create nested routes?
because before i click on the link that executes the above route. i will be in this route

```
Router.route('itemDetails', {
  path: '/item/:_id',
  template: 'itemDetails',
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    Session.set( "currentRoute", "itemDetails" );
    Session.set("itemId", this.params._id);
    this.next();
  }
});
```

and this route works fine i can see the item _id, is it possible to create another route inside it that has for example this path `/item/:_id/screenshots`?

I have the _id stored in `Session.get("itemId")`. Is it possible to call it in the path of the route somehow?

I tried `'/item' + '/screenshots' + '/' + Session.get("itemId")` but didn't work

or there is other way to solve it?

Comment: On the page where the link is populated can you right click the link and inspect it to make sure it is actually adding the {{_id}} part? if it goes to /screenshots/ directly I suspect it isn't getting the id added in the link in the first place as your code shouldn't clear the id or redirect you

Comment: @PhilipPryde will try it now

Comment: @PhilipPryde nothing appears in the console when i inspect

Comment: What do you get with Right clicking and  copy link address? Does it show the full url you are expecting?

Comment: @PhilipPryde i think i misunderstood you, what i did is right click and inspect on the page, and then navigated to the console to see if there is any errors, isn't it the correct way? when i didn't i saw am empty console. I edited my question, i added something may help elaborate further the problem

Comment: Nope not quite what I was meaning. I am meaning look at the address the link is pointing to on the first page where you have your <a> tag and see if it is actually sending the id attached to the url or if for some reason that template is not filling in {{_id}}.

Comment: @PhilipPryde seems that the _id is not sent, i have the id stored in Session.get("itemId"), is it possible i can use it in the path of the route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107071/discussion-between-philip-pryde-and-behrouz-riahi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the code in the question, the 404 page is occurring due to it not being passed an id into the path, the browser says `/screenshots/` and not `/screenshots/randomId` because it is only being passed that from the link.

As per additions to the question and chat with Behrouz: Because the value is stored in session we can use

```
Template.registerHelper('session',function(input){ 
    return Session.get(input); 
});
```

to register a global template helper called session which can be called with {{session session_var_name}} and create the link as below:

`<h4><a href="/screenshots/{{session "itemId"}}">Click to view the Screenshots</a>`